# In Oracle => symbol used for

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

```
DECLARE
price_to_update NUMBER(6,2) := 20;

updated_price NUMBER(6,2) := 0;

BEGIN


dbms_output.put_line('price before ' || price_to_update);

dbms_output.put_line('updated_price before ' || updated_price);

changePrice (old_price => price_to_update, new_price => updated_price);

dbms_output.put_line('price_to_update after update ' || price_to_update);

dbms_output.put_line('updated_price after update ' || updated_price);

END;

/
```

in this example user is using => symbol 
i am unable to figure out for what purpose user using it ...
KIndly Help me out ...
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 8):

It's the [named notation for subprogram parameters](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/08_subs.htm#847) (vs. positional notation). This syntax allows to:

1. Swap parameters.
2. Omit optional parameters.

Example:

```
PROCEDURE FOO(A VARCHAR2:=NULL, B VARCHAR2:=NULL, C VARCHAR2:=NULL)
```

... can be called as:

```
FOO(C=>'FOO', A=>'BAR');
```

Comment: It also allows to skip optional parameters. For example a procdedure like this: `procedure foobar(a varchar2:=null, b varchar2:=null, c varchar2:=null, d varchar2:=null)` can be called like this: `foobar(b=>'foo', d=>'bar');`

Comment: @ammoQ - Certainly, I'm including it in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is called "named parameter notation".  If you have this procedure:

```
procedure changeprice (old_price number, new_price number);
```

then you can call it with positional notation:

```
changeprice (price_to_update, updated_price);
```

or you can call it with positional notation:

```
changeprice (old_price => price_to_update, new_price => updated_price);
```

See [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00825) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle PL/SQL also supports called functions with named parameters (as opposed to positional parameters). This is what the => does.